# Read file with pattern in C++

Tags: c++, file, getline

I want to read a file that has a pattern and I want to save the values at the end. E.g. if it's a room it has three values size values that have to be saved and so on.

The file I want to read looks like this:

```
room
{
    size 5 3.3 6
    wallpaper
    {
        texture flower.bmp
        tiling 3 1
    }
}
object vase
{
    translation 0.2 0 0.5
    roation 0 1 0 0
    scaling 1 1 1
    model vase.obj
    parent tisch
}
Object tisch
{
    translation 2.0 0 3
    roation 0 1 0 45
    scaling 1.5 1 1
    model tisch.obj
    parent NULL
}
```

I started this way. How can I read and save the next lines for room and object?

```
fstream osh("/Users/torhoehn/Desktop/room.osh", ios::in);
    string line;

    if (osh.good()) {
        while (getline(osh, line, '\0')) {
            if (line.compare("room")) {
                cout << "Found room" << endl;

            }

            if (line.compare("object")) {
                cout << "Found object" << endl;
            }
        }
        osh.close();

    }
```

Comment: First of all try to find an existing library to read and parse the file format you're having. And if there's none (doubtful unless you made up the file format yourself, or if this is for e.g. a University assignment) then you might want to read about parsing and/or state-machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the input operator:

```
string noun, junk;

while(osh >> noun) {
  if (noun == "room") {
    cout << "Found room ";
    osh >> junk >> junk;  // for the brace and "size"
    float length, width, height;
    osh >> length >> width >> height;
    cout << length << " long and " << breadth << " wide" << endl;
    ...
  }

  if ( noun == "object" ) {
    osh >> noun;            // what kind of object?
    if ( noun == "vase" ) {
      cout << "found vase ";
      osh >> junk >> junk;
      float translationX, translationY, translationZ;
      osh >> translationX >> translationY >> translationZ;
      ...
    }
    if ( noun == "tisch" ) {
      cout << "found tisch ";
      osh >> junk >> junk;
      float translationX, translationY, translationZ;
      osh >> translationX >> translationY >> translationZ;
      ...
    }
    ...
  }     // object
  ...
```

After you have that working perfectly, you can consider writing constructors for the `Room` class, the `Vase` class, and so on,
which will make the code much cleaner.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you! But the name of the object is not known so I checked if noun == "object", but how can I repeat this for more than object?